# How can I make the second form follow whatever happens in the main form?

Tags: winforms, forms, vb.net-2010

I have a two forms. The main form, and the other is where I put the background image. I set the main form transparent so you can see the background. I created another form for the background because I want only the contents in the main form to be scrolled, living alone the image.
The problem is when I restore down the main form, the other form won't restore down. I used the **OnSizeChanged** event but it only have the Minimize, Maximize, and Normal function. It worked so far but only on the minimize and maximize function. Can anybody give me a code for making the second form follow whatever the main form do? Like for example when the main form is moved. Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is really a bad idea. Use OnPaint event on Your form to paint the image in the background and keep it position "fixed".

Comment: @GrzegorzW I hope to have the effects just like in twitter. The background is fixed. When you move the scrollbar it doesn't scroll along the contents so I made a separate form for the background.

Comment: Just use OnLocationChanged to make it follow.